# Magento 1.9 File Upload Showing Serialized Value on Cart Page

Tags: magento, serialization, magento-1.9

I have the following observer setup:

```
        <checkout_cart_save_before>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_cartupdate>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyModule_CartUpdate_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>docustomthings</method>
                </mymodule_cartupdate>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_save_before>
```

The observer method is:

```
    $cart = $observer->getCart();
    $cartQuote = $cart->getQuote();
    $cartItems = $cartQuote->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        $product = $cartItem->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getOrderOptions($cartItem->getProduct());
        // more logic here....
    }
```

The problem is that getting the order options is causing the Cart and admin to display the serialized value, instead of a link to the file upload.

e.g.

```
a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:5:"title";s:45:"5B0C5B2B-ABD3-4291-93D3-0F7C01583454 (1).jpeg";s:10:"quote_path";s:69:"/media/custom_options/quote/5/B/cdd7a1b34b3b72acc7e3b90d0acc818c.jpeg";s:10:"order_path";s:69:"/media/custom_options/order/5/B/cdd7a1b34b3b72acc7e3b90d0acc818c.jpeg";s:8:"fullpath";s:113:"/media/custom_options/quote/5/B/cdd7a1b34b3b72acc7e3b90d0acc818c.jpeg";s:4:"size";s:6:"852491";s:5:"width";i:505;s:6:"height";i:504;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"cdd7a1b34b3b72acc7e3";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";N;s:3:"key";s:20:"cdd7a1b34b3b72acc7e3";}}}
```

Instead of showing:

```
5B0C5B2B-ABD3-4291-93D3-0F7C01583454 (1).jpeg 505 x 504 px.
```

What I'm trying to do is get the options so that I can check if a certain bundle option has been selected and then manipulate the price. The code behind this all works, but for some reason `$product = $cartItem->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getOrderOptions($cartItem->getProduct());` causes this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using unserialize()

Comment: Where would I use this?